# TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder: '' from 'form.filter()'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to put some values of my queryset in a html template.
this is my html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
              {% for i in form.filter(university="UPF - Universitat Pompeu Fabra") %}
                <li ><a href="#">{{ i.degree }}</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

But when I charge the page, it launch this error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '(university="UPF - Universitat Pompeu Fabra")' from 'form.filter(university="UPF - Universitat Pompeu Fabra")'
```

The value of the queryset printed in the shell is the following one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBHH5.jpg)

```
My views is the following one:

    from .models import Universitys

def index(request):
    universitys = Universitys.objects.all()
    context = {"form":universitys}
    return render(request,"index.html", context)
```

and models:

```
class Universitys(models.Model):
 data = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
 university = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 degree = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 degreeMark = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=5)

 def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %f' % (self.university, self.degree, self.degreeMark)
```

If you can help me, I'll it grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Django default template engine doesn't allow this kind of operation inside the template. The recommended way of doing this is to add a context variable on the context with the result of that queryset and use that variable on the templates' forloop. Something like:

```
def index(request):
    universities = Universities.objects.filter(university="UPF - Universitat Pompeu Fabra")
    context = {"universities": universities}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

and on the template:

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      {% for i in universities %}
        <li ><a href="#">{{ i.degree }}</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

If you are only using the `degree` field another thing you can do is get only this value on the queryset. So i would also change the `universities` queryset to :

```
universities = Universities.objects.filter(university='UPF - Universitat Pompeu Fabra').values_list('degree', flat=True)
```

For more about `values_list`, please refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: The other way that you coment me to use degree is correct but in templates i can not use it, in the answer I explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I understand the solution that you explain me, but I need filter the degree who depends on the university that you choose. For this reason I pass all objects in the views to can process the database as I prefer, I didn't know that it was not possible realise this kind of operation in django templates.

I explain again my problem, to see if you see other solution. I pass the models explained in the post, as I'm doing a dropdown menus or menu select for my app, and I need filter the degree that I choose from the university that I had choosed before.

the template is following one:

```
<select id="font">
    {% for e in form %}
      <option>{{ e.university }}</option>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select id="font">
    {% for i in form.filter(university="UPF - Universitat Pompeu Fabra") %}
      <option>{{ i.degree }}</option>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <p><label for="basic-url">2. Crea tu escenario en las PAU</label></p>
```

I'm think a possible solution it would be a post method first with university, and depends of the choosing, do a objects.filter() in the views and pass another context again to the template. I'm not sure about this solution and possibly, there are another way to do it better..